# How to simulate keyboard button in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I have to simulate button press in my script.

I have a big application running in which I have to put some values in some fields and press enter so proceed to next panel and so on.

I got idea about simulating ENTER using echo "\n", but unable to find out how to simulate buttons like Function keys, arrow keys and pressing alphanumeric characters.

Any idea will be helpful

Comment: https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect

Comment: You cannot simulate button presses per se, because `bash` doesn't not know or care about the keyboard. It only reads from files, which means it reads the byte sequence *generated* by your keyboard, according to your terminal emulator's configuration.

Comment: @chepner You might want to post this as an answer since this is the only correct answer to this question :)

Comment: You can use `xdotool` to simulate X11 key presses from a bash script on Linux

Comment: @chepner is there way to find out byte sequence provided by keyboard for the particular key.

Comment: @chepner and will echo "byte sequence" will work to simulate particular key?

Answer (score 1):

Just Create an empty file and write the following simple bash script inside:

```
#!/bin/bash
xdotool key alt+shift+F12
```

Save the file as ".sh" and make it executable.

You can add any set of keys and this tool (xdotool) can also allow you to automate the mouse. You can create very useful scripts with it if used properly.

Happy coding!

For more learning, checkout this tool manual: [men xdotool](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/xdotool.1.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can use [expect](http://expect.sourceforge.net/) to do this.